# Graphical bugs and laggy input on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

For a month now, I've been using Ubuntu 20.04, and all of a sudden I am experiencing major graphical flaws.

Mouse input is laggy sometimes, the mouse stays in the same place. Keyboard input is laggy as well, characters often take a while to show up on screen. When switching between windows or between tabs in Firefox, it sometimes takes a few moments before the correct content is displayed over the "old" content from the other window / tab.

All of these problems suddenly appeared a couple of days ago. When switching over to Windows 10, none of these problems exist.

I have tried reinstalling Ubuntu 20.04, Ubuntu 21.10, Ubuntu 19. I also tried the nouveau graphics driver, the NVIDIA driver that came as "additional drivers" with Ubuntu in different versions. And I also tried drivers that I have downloaded directly from NVIDIA. None of these steps have made any difference so far.

I'm on a Dell Laptop with an additional NVIDIA RTX 3060 graphics chip.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you :)